# Match a column values to a list of vector of codes and create a column indicating which vector it belongs to

Tags: r

I have a `tibble` with codes which need to match to another list of vectors containing codes. So, in the `tibble`, a new column would be created indicating which vector does the code belong to.

The `tibble`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(id = 1:6, code = c("1502", "0223", "", "0380", "0421", "7958"))

> df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id code  
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 "1502"
2     2 "0223"
3     3 ""    
4     4 "0380"
5     5 "0421"
6     6 "7958"
```

The sample of the list of code vectors:

```
code_list <- 
  list(
  "0" = "",
  "2" = c("0031", "0202", "0223", "0362", "0380", "0381", "03810", "03811", "03812", "03819", "0382", "0383", "03840", "03841", "03842", "03843", "03844", "03849", "0388", "0389", "0545", "449", "77181", "7907", "99591", "99592"),
  "5" = c("042", "0420", "0421", "0422", "0429", "0430", "0431", "0432", "0433", "0439", "0440", "0449", "07953", "27910", "27919", "79571", "7958","V08"),
  "12" = c("1500", "1501", "1502", "1503", "1504", "1505", "1508", "1509", "2301", "V1003"))
```

The column code_cat is the result I am looking for. The code "1502" belongs to vector "12" in the code_list and so on. I could have used one of the `join` functions had the code_list been a data-frame. But as it is a list, I'm not sure how to proceed. Or maybe we can try converting the code_list to a data-frame.

Required result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id code   code_cat
  <int> <chr>  <chr>   
1     1 "1502" 12      
2     2 "0223" 2       
3     3 ""     0       
4     4 "0380" 2       
5     5 "0421" 5       
6     6 "7958" 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
      left_join(enframe(code_list) %>% unnest(value), by = c('code' = 'value')) %>% 
      select(1,2,'code_cat' = name)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id code   code_cat
  <int> <chr>  <chr>   
1     1 "1502" 12      
2     2 "0223" 2       
3     3 ""     0       
4     4 "0380" 2       
5     5 "0421" 5       
6     6 "7958" 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution. It first builds a list of matrices matching codes and codes list members. Then gets the list's names and creates the new column.

```
m <- lapply(seq_along(code_list), function(i){
  code <- which(df$code %in% code_list[[i]])
  cbind(code, name = i)
})
m <- do.call(rbind, m)
m <- m[order(m[,1]),]
df$code_cat <- names(code_list)[ m[, 2] ]

df
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#     id code   code_cat
#  <int> <chr>  <chr>   
#1     1 "1502" 12      
#2     2 "0223" 2       
#3     3 ""     0       
#4     4 "0380" 2       
#5     5 "0421" 5       
#6     6 "7958" 5 

rm(m)    # final clean up
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    code_cat = unlist(
      lapply(code, function(x) names(
        which(
          sapply(code_list, function(y) any(y %in% x)))))))
```